# Are duplicate SQL table rows inherently problematic?

Tags: sql

I'm about to create a SQL database, containing two tables, that will be used to represent [order books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_book_(trading)).

Specifically, the database will contain order book snapshots at different points in time (append-only).

The way I plan to represent order books will rely on duplicate rows to work without issues. Can I rely on this being the case?

I plan to represent order books using two tables:

1. `orderbook` (id: INT, venue: VARCHAR, base: VARCHAR, quote: VARCHAR)
2. `order` (orderbook_id: INT, is_buy_order: BOOL, quantity: DECIMAL, price: DECIMAL)

So, an order book will have a unique ID (to which an order will point, hereby defining which order book an order belongs to). But the orders inside any given order book will not be identified by a unique ID.

I'm using this representation because I don't need to identify any particular order (I'm not implementing a matching engine using a SQL database). All the queries I will need involve queries on all orders in an order book. Also, I will never need to update or delete single orders (the database is append-only).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bad idea to me.  First, you can say that you never want to update or delete any rows.  That's like saying you will do everything perfect the first time and make no mistakes.  It seems like a dangerous assumption.

Second, when I have worked with trading orders, the orders were definitely ordered, by time (or insertion order into the orders table).  There is probably a natural ordering.

Third, it is *really easy* to add a unique id to a table.  You have not specified the database, but almost all support a `serial`, `identity`, or `auto_increment` columns that do this automatically.

Comment: If we assume that I haven't done everything perfect the first time (a reasonable assumption), then I will need to migrate in the future. This migration can easily add a unique ID. Let's focus on whether duplicate rows are inherently problematic (or some interesting queries that require a unique order ID). With regards to order IDs, I'm fetching orders from cryptocurrency exchanges via their public API, and the majority of them don't include order IDs (probably because users of this API don't care which order -- out of two orders with the same price -- is matched).

Comment: The natural ordering of orders in an order book is primarily by price and secondarily by the time they're received at the venue (always ascending by time; ascending by price for sell orders; descending by price for buy orders). But, again, most exchanges don't include order timestamps in the output data of their public APIs.

Comment: One option is to preprocess the input data and merge same-priced orders, and then use the price as a component in the unique order ID. So, if `orderA` and `orderB` have the same price, then replace these two orders with a new order of the given price and a quantity equal to the sum of `orderA` and `orderB`. This way `(orderbook_id, is_buy_order, price)` becomes a unique order ID if we assume order books may be crossed, and `(orderbook_id, price)` if we exclude the possibility of crossed order books.

Comment: Great, so it sounds like you've identified a key for `order`.  There's no need to add a column if the table already has a key.